# If x = .48 and y = -0.52, what is the formula for finding x(i) + y(i) = 0?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

I'm not sure how to title this, so please feel free to edit title.

I'm trying to zero out x and y, meaning how many x and y would I need for them to equal 0 -- i.e. be neutral?

For example, if x = 50 and y = -100, I would need x(2) + y = 0

What would the formula for this be?

Comment: You require $i$ to be integer, right?

Comment: as close to an integer as possible. Its OK if it doesn't equal 0 exactly.

Comment: You basically need to find the least common multiple of the absolute values. In your $x=50$, $y=-100$, case, find the LCM of $50$ and $100$, which is 100. To obtain $100$, you need to multiply $x$ by 2, and $-y$ by $1$. 

If you don't know LCM of fractions: https://eu.edugain.com/articles/6/LCM-of-Fractions/

Comment: I don't know what kind of purpose you have, but the question will make more sense with $i$ being an integer.

Comment: Its for option pricing theory in finance in order to achieve delta neutrality. If a call option has a delta of 0.48, and a put option has a delta of -0.52 how many calls and puts would i need to purchase for delta to equal -- or be closest to - zero.

Comment: To have $ax + by = 0$, we want $\frac{x}{y} =\frac{b}{-a}$. Your problem is thus solved if you can write $\frac{x}{y}$ in reduced form. In the case $x = 0.48$ and $y = -0.52$, we have $\frac{x}{y} = \frac{48}{-52} = \frac{12}{-13}$, so you would take $a = 13$ and $b=12$ (i.e. buy $13$ of the call options and buy $12$ of the put options). By the way, even if you didn't know the reduced form (i.e. just considered $\frac{48}{52}$), you could take $a = 52$ and $b=48$ and still get a correct answer, you would just not be using the "minimal" possible portfolio.

Comment: Assuming your $x$ and $y$ are to two decimal places always, $100x$ and $100y$ will be integer, so you could just buy $100x$ call options and buy $100y$ put options. But to get the "minimal" portfolio, you would need to reduce $\frac{100x}{100y}$ to lowest terms, which effectively means dividing through top and bottom by the greatest common divisor of $100x$ and $100|y|$ (so you would take $a = 100x/d$ and $b=100y/d$, where $d = \gcd (100x,100|y|)$).

Answer (score 0):

Clearly 52x + 48y = 0.
Let r be the gcd of 52 and 48.
Then $52nx/r + 48ny/r = 0$, for all positive integers n.